# Selecting different values for pkg_deb's "package" and "architecture" attributes

Tags: bazel

I am using pkg_deb to build debian packages for different target platforms.  I would like to use the same target in my BUILD file to achieve that, but the attributes "package" and "architecture" cannot use "select" because they are used in the "outputs" attribute of the rule itself.

Is there a different way to make the "package" and "architecture" attributes configurable?

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue as well. I believe the problem is how architecture is used in the macro, as opposed to being expanded in the rule. I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/pull/263), but it's unclear how this might interact with compatibility constraints.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

- do not use Bazel's built-in @bazel_tools/.../pkg_deb.  It is deprecated and will be removed at release 5.0
- switch to the module at https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg
- wait for https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/pull/282 to be merged
- use `select` on `architecture` and let the default package naming create `{package_name}-{version}-{architecture}.deb` (& similar for .changes)

The longer answer is

- do the above, but don't bother with the `select`
- use `package_variables` to extract the CPU name from you C++ toolchain

See the examples of how to do this at
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/tree/main/examples/naming_package_files